# how to parse some mails from html code

Tags: linux, bash, regex, html

I want to build a little bash script to detect some mails in a HTML-code.
currently, I am not sure how can I build the right regex to auto-detect emails from HTML.

I tried this regex with curl:

```sh
egrep -o "\S*@.*\.\S*"
```

But this includes all non-alpha characters until the first space.

For a little example:

```html
</span></p><p class="footertext"><span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Email&nbsp;</span><br><a href="mailto:regex@mydomain.com" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"
```

Now I want to auto-detect only this part: `regex@mydomain.com`

Does somebody have any idea?

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you just want to get whatever comes between the "mailto: and the ", then this would do the trick:

```
grep -oP '(?<="mailto:)[^"]+(?=")'
```

It uses *positive lookbehind* and *positive lookahead* which is supported by the Perl regex syntax (-P flag).

If you need additional validation of the address, you might want to look into expressions like the ones discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression

UPDATE:

If you don't want to fall back to overly complex expressions, this should do the job:

```
grep -oP $'[^\'",<>:\\s]+@[^\'",<>:\\s]+'
```

You can easily add additional delimiting characters within the square brackets.

UPDATE 2:

If you also want to match something like this: regex @ example.com

```
grep -oP $'[^\'",<>:\\s]+\\s*@\\s*[^\'",<>:\\s]+'
```

Comment: thanks. the line above <a href="mailto:regex@mydomain.com" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" was only an example. i want a regex that matchs to this line too:

<a href="regex@mydomain.com" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"

or

<a href=>regex@mydomain.com< style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"

i think i need a regex that include all alpha characters until the first non-alpha like "<,>,;," etc."

because the developer places the mail between different symbolic.

Comment: Ah, I see. I updated my answer with a more robust version that should handle most cases.

Comment: Many thanks. It works out. I've added the symbol ";"

grep -oP $'[^\'";,<>:\\s]+@[^\'",<>:\\s]+'